# Need to split a string with line breaks by finding PHP tags

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to split a string with line breaks by finding PHP tags.

Here is my code I have so far:

```
$contents = '
some test
some more test
test 1
<?php 
test 2 and test 4
test 6
?>
test 7
test 9
<?php 
test 10
test 12
>?
test 13
<?php test 14
test 16 
?>
test 17
';
```

As you can tell, the PHP code is the EVEN test examples, and the ODD test examples are outside the PHP tags.

What I am looking to do is extract into an array every iteration of php code:

Expected result:

```
array(
    [0] =>  <?php 
            test 2 and test 4
            test 6
            ?>

    [1] =>  <?php 
            test 10
            test 12
            >?

    [2] =>  <?php test 14
            test 16 
            ?>
)
```

I have tried with `preg_split` by the end tags, and then by capturing the `$explode[1]` with the beginning tags but my code is wrong...

```
$ends = preg_split("/[?>]/s", $contents, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
print_r($ends);
foreach($ends as $flufcode){
  $trimcode = explode('<?php', $flufcode);
  echo $trimcode . " next:";
}
```

So far my `preg_split` does not work, I believe my regex is not scanning after the line breaks.

Comment: In line "test 12 >?" you have a synatx error. It must be 

"test 12 ?>"   I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code is wrong. And wrong expected result... anyway. And with regex parsing code like `<?php echo '?>'; ?>` will be failed.

For properly and easy parsing you should use [token_get_all](http://php.net/token_get_all). Example for you.

```
$tokens = token_get_all($contents);

$catch = false;
$codes = array();
$index = 0;
foreach ($tokens as $token)
    {
    if (is_array($token) && $token[0] == \T_OPEN_TAG)
        {
        $catch = true;
        $index++;
        $codes[$index] = '';
        }
    if ($catch)
        $codes[$index] .= is_array($token) ? $token[1] : $token;

    if (is_array($token) && $token[0] == \T_CLOSE_TAG)
        {
        $catch = false;
        }
    }

var_export($codes);
```

Will produce with your provided data.

```
array (
  1 => '<?php
test 2 and test 4
test 6
?>
',
  2 => '<?php
test 10
test 12
>?
test 13
<?php test 14
test 16
?>
',
)
```

Comment: You made it work. I dont fully understand the functions but I am able to use your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question mark is a regex metacharacter -- try escaping it:

```
$ends = preg_split("/\\?>/sm", $contents, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
```

Comment: The result is the same? $ends is an array with the entire contents in [0].

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
preg_match_all("/<\?php.*?\?>/s", $contents, $matches);
```

This captures everything between `<?php` and `?>` reluctantly (not greedily).  Note that the `$matches` array will be nested.